# The scrolling widget that appears half way down the page

Tags: javascript, css

I am interested in knowing and understanding how this website https://medium.com/swlh/how-i-turned-a-hobby-into-a-multi-million-dollar-company-543462a6eb75 page is showing the left widget with subscriber count etc. that appears when you scroll down the page. thanks!

Comment: It's position fixed element that appears with transition after you pass certain scrollTop value. There is probably event listener binded to scroll and its checking scrollTop value and when it passes certain treshold, it applies some class to html element to show it and start transition. I can make some example code if you want

Answer (score 0):

It probably uses a fixed property you can set it by adding
`position: fixed`

here is more information about it https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp